# Docker volume folders are empty

Tags: docker

I need to dockerize WordPress so this is my `compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: artanetwork_wp
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: artanetwork
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: artanetwork
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: artanetwork
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./extensions:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions
      - ./config:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: artanetwork_db
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: artanetwork
      MYSQL_DATABASE: artanetwork
      MYSQL_USER: artanetwork
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: artanetwork
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress:
  extensions:
  config:
  mysql:
```

The issue is, `wordpress` and `mysql` volumes are working fine (they are populated with files and folders) but `extensions` and `config` are empty while the corresponding paths inside the image are not.

What I'm missing?

Edit:

And I noticed that those folders are emptied inside the image while before adding them as a volume, there are not!

So for `wordpress` and `mysql` the host is populated from the image, and for another two the image is populated from the host!

Comment: Have you tried mounting the volumes by absolute path?

Comment: Yes. Same result. ```extensions``` and ```config``` are there but empty.

Comment: If you change the order between the the volumes in the `wordpress` container, for example attempting to mount `config` 1st, does that change anything?

Comment: What you have right now are *bind mounts* and not volumes. Use `wordpress:/var/www/html` (no `./`), delete the existing volume if there is one and try running your container again.

Comment: @HansKilian The ```wordpress``` and ```mysql``` mounts work fine. The issue is with the other two.

Comment: @HansKilian The reason for what I'm doing is that I need to manipulate the files in those 4 folders so mount is better than volume. However I don't understand why two folders are populated and two are not.